# array implode with '<', odd behavior

Tags: php, arrays, implode

```
$b = array("one", "two", "three");
$z = implode('<', $b);
var_dump($z);
```

outputs: string(13) "one

can anyone explain this.

PHP 5.4.4

Comment: You're viewing the result in a web browser, it thinks `<` is an opening HTML tag, view the source of the page and you'll see the correct result (it's not a bug).

Comment: The actual output is `one<two<three`: http://3v4l.org/i7FML

Comment: yep, just view the source and you'll see what you expected

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think the reason it didn't make sense is because I viewed the source on Google Chrome and it said 'string(13) "one' yet, in Firefox the correct source is shown as 'string(13) "one<two<three"'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

view html source result , the real result is :

```
string(13) "one<two<three"
```

as eis mentioned :

> This is what it is supposed to do. You are looking at it in your
>   browser, where it doesn't show you the results as-is, but tries to
>   render it as HTML.

so if you want to see it as plain text , simpy filter html tags :

```
<?php
$b = array("one", "two", "three");
$z = implode('<', $b);
$z = htmlspecialchars($z);
var_dump($z);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution on escaping the output to get the desired result

Answer (score 2):

```
>php implode.php
string(13) "one<two<three"
```

This is what it is supposed to do. You are looking at it in your browser, where it doesn't show you the results as-is, but tries to render it as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If your want print text as html, please usage special charset:

```
<?php
$ar = array('one', 'two'/** ... **/);
print implode('&lt;', $ar);
```

For view all special charsets: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php